# Square brackets getting changed to encoded character [WordPress]

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

Here is the problem, I have a JS code block that I would very much like to keep inline for speed reasons. This has not presented a problem in the past but for this specific function this is happening. I am using the PHP Output Buffer to render this through a shortcode.

Code that is rendered:

```
function get_price(arr, val) {
          var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
            var s = c.trim();
            if (/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)) {
              var range = s.split("-");
              if (+val >= parseInt(range[0]) && +val <= parseInt(range&#091;1&#093;)) {
                a = arr&#091;c&#093;;
              }
            } else {
              s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
              if (+val >= +s) {
                a = arr[c];
              }
            }
            return a;
          }, 0);
          return price;
}
```

Code that is sent:

```
    function get_price(arr, val) {
                    var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
                      var s = c.trim();
                      if (/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)) {
                        var range = s.split("-");
                        if (+val >= parseInt(range[0]) && +val <= parseInt(range[1])) {
                          a = arr[c];
                        }
                      } else {
                        s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
                        if (+val >= +s) {
                          a = arr[c];
                        }
                      }
                      return a;
                    }, 0);
                    return price;
    }
```

I am at my wits end as too why this is happening so any help is appreciated!

I can also send more code if needed but don't want to overload my question with unnecessary code.

Comment: Can you try escaping the square brackets (with \)?

Comment: Why are only some of the brackets affected do you think?

Comment: I guess thats because you are trying render it through shortcode. Shortcode itself is rendered via square brackets. Though I am not very sure about the reason, its just the very first thought top of the mind.

Comment: If that were the case then it should be changing all the square brackets but it is not

Answer (score 0):

So... Not sure why this worked but I converted the 2 offending areas into JS vars and then the code was no longer getting encoded.

```
 function get_price(arr, val) {
          var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
            var s = c.trim();
            if (/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)) {
              var range = s.split("-");
              var t1 = parseInt(range[1]); // new added var
              var t2 = arr[c];  // new added var 
              if (+val >= parseInt(range[0]) && +val <= t1) { // replaced code with t1 here
                a = t2; // replaced code with t2 here
              }
            } else {
              s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
              if (+val >= +s) {
                a = arr[c];
              }
            }
            return a;
          }, 0);
          return price;
}
```

If anyone know why and wants to help the universe by sharing their knowledge then go right ahead. If not then hopefully this helps someone!